# Init script header not resolving dependency

Tags: linux, boot, init-script, suse

I need to run a `/usr/sbin` command in my init script, so there is a dependency for the `/usr` filesytem to be mounted.

To resolve the dependency, I put `$local_fs` or `boot.localfs` (I also tried `$remote_fs` and `$all`) in the required-start field of init script header, but it does still mount the `/usr` filesystem and my command in the initscript still fails with "command not found" error.

I could resolve the issue by adding `boot.localfs` in the `.depend.boot` file, but why could not I resolve from the required-start init script header?

Edit: I'm using the SUSE Linux 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, it might just help others. The problem was that just adding the dependency of `boot.localfs` in my init script was not enough. After adding the dependency, one needs to run the insserv command (as `insserv boot.myinitscript`) to enable the init script that is changed and it automatically resolves the boot dependency order by adding necessary things to `.depend.boot` file, which I was adding manually before.